# python 3 idle window stuck at full height

Tags: python-3.x, window, python-idle

this is annoying. even when i change it from the option to a different height and width. every time I open the script window or the idle. it's at max height. I also the disabled the height option and still the same.

I uninstalled and reinstalled. but the same also.

is there a place where the python settings are saved aside from the main folder?.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: Which version?  Which OS?  Which 'height option'?  In 3.6, I cannot reproduce the issue on Windows.  It sounds like the Windows => Zoom Height option is somehow stuck on for you.  For me, it only applies to one window and is turned off whenever a window is opened.  User customizations are saved in <Home directory>/.idlerc/*.cfg.

Comment: @jurgemaister I did`t ask for any coding service. you seem to not understood my problem.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy thank you. I found the folder inside users\PCname\.idlerc

Answer (score 0):

folder location for idle settings (windows) is: users\PCname.idlerc.
thanks @TerryJanReedy